# Access a value from one class to another in csharp

Tags: c#, class, interface, web-performance

i have two class but i want to the value string 'version' from the class LastFridayDate to class Buildversion.

Hello everyone, i have two class but i want to the value string 'version' from the class LastFridayDate to class Buildversion.

Am not able to access the String version, any help from someone.

my code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebTesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.LoadTesting;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace PTUtil
{

    [System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("GetVersion")]
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("Get the Build No Version")]
    public class LastFridayDate : WebTestPlugin
    {
        String version;

        //Setting the version in the usercontext
        public override void PostWebTest(object sender, PostWebTestEventArgs e)
        {
            version = e.WebTest.Context["Param_ClientSoftwareVersion"].ToString();
        }

    }

    /// Specify a name for use in the user interface.
    /// The user sees this name in the Add Validation dialog box.
    [DisplayName("Build Version Processing")]
    /// Specify a description for use in the user interface
    /// The user sees this description in the Add Validation dialog box.
    [Description("Add the build version for a load test")]
    public class BuildVersion : ILoadTestPlugin
    {
        [DisplayName("Comment")]
        [Description("What the plugin is for")]
        public string theComment { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Test Type")]
        [Description("M for Manual or A for Automatic")]
        [DefaultValue("A")]
        public string connectionStr { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Version Context Parameter")]
        [Description("The Context Parameter for the build version")]
        [DefaultValue("{{Param_ClientSoftwareVersion}}")]
        public string Version_param { get; set; }

        LoadTest m_loadTest;

        public void Initialize(LoadTest loadTest)
        {
            m_loadTest = loadTest;

            m_loadTest.LoadTestFinished += new EventHandler(m_loadTest_LoadTestFinished);
        }

        // Do it *after* the Load Test.
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------

        void m_loadTest_LoadTestFinished(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your field `version` does not have modifier, which makes it private by default. Use public modifier to make it visible: `public String version`; Read more here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it public and I suggest you to use a property and initialize it somewhere. Like in the constructor or auto-initialize.

```
public string Version {get; set; } = String.Empty
```

Comment: Am still not able even i have use public string Version {get; set; }.

Comment: I tried a completely generic answer, now I need more details. Where exactly are you trying to use `Version`?

Comment: i want to use the version on the Buildversion class in m_loadTest_LoadTestFinished method.